# Opening new tab in firefox using selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox

I am trying to open new tab in current WebDriver instance and I am using this command  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "\t");` but it did not work. I am currently using Selenium 2.53 and Firefox version 28 in a Linux system.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Firefox 28 is badly out of date, right?

Answer (score 1):

All you do by that command is to send some keys so the HTML body. It does not affect the browsers menu at all.

Configuring Firefox for test automation is done by the help of Firefox profiles. So you should [create a profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) which opens new tabs instead of windows in `about:preferences`.

You can then use the profile in your test code by instantiating the driver like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxProfile(new File("/path/to/ff_profile")));
```

See [javadoc](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html) for details.